# How to pick dynamic files from a specific folder and then export to SQL server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ms-access-2010, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have been trying to create an SSIS task which picks the MS Access file from a specific folder
and then export to SQL Server ( if that file/table found in server then skip else export).

I am new to SSIS, i have used script task to select the file names dynamically and then trying to move, but I end up getting unsatisfied results . Even I have googled and got few ideas, but still not able to get it the way I wanted. Any detailed  help would be very helpful.

**Note :** Here, am not always sure about the filename from that folder(i.e dynamic)

Comment: "but I end up getting unsatisfied results". What results you get and why are they unsatisfied?

Comment: got errors, i din't get the concept of choosing a file in dynamic way from specific folder

Comment: What error you got and what you tried?

Comment: file Not found when i have written script , have reffered this [link] : sirhttps://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb42c461-1f63-4283-8a99-1d3b90cde53d/how-to-pick-up-latest-file-in-a-folder-using-ssis-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for dynamically selecting files.  Since you're unsure about the filename, I'm assuming this is a parameter or variable.  The following is an example of checking a folder from a variable for the given file name and loading it to an SSIS `object` variable.  These files are then loaded into a SQL Server table using the `Foreach Loop`.  You mentioned files as opposed to a single file, so this example assumes that only part of the file name is passed in, such as would be the case if the date/UID was appended to the beginning or end of the file name.

- Add a Script Task, with the parameters/variables holding the file and folder name as `ReadOnlyVariables` and the object variable which will store the file names during execution as a `ReadWriteVariable`.  The code for this is at the end of this post. 
  The `string.IndexOf` method is used to check for files containing the given text, with the `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` parameter used to make this search case-insensitive.  This example uses a variable for the file path and a parameter for the file name (denoted by `$Package` in the parameter name).
- Add a `Foreach Loop` of the `Foreach From Variable Enumerator` Enumerator type.  Add the object variable that was populated in the Script Task as the Variable on the Collection page.  On the Variable Mappings pane, add a string variable at index 0.  This will need to be an empty string variable that will hold the name of each file.
- Create a Flat File Connection Manager from an example data file.  Make sure that the column names and data types are appropriately configured.  To set the file name dynamically, choose the `ConnectionString` expression (click the ellipsis of the Expression property in the Properties window of the connection manager) and add the same string variable from the Mappings Pane of the `Foreach Loop`.
- Inside the `Foreach Loop`, add a Data Flow Task with a Flat File Source using the same connection manager.  Then add either an OLE DB or SQL Server Destination with your destination connection and connect the flat file source to this.  I've found SQL Server Destinations to perform better, but you'll want to verify this in your own environment before making the choice.  Choose the necessary table and map the columns from the flat file source accordingly.

  ```
  List<string> fileList = new List<string>();

  //get files from input directory
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::FilePathVariable"].Value.ToString());

  foreach (FileInfo f in di.GetFiles())
  {
      //check for files with name containing text
      if (f.Name.IndexOf(Dts.Variables["$Package::FileNameParameter"].Value.ToString(), 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
      {
          fileList.Add(f.FullName);
      }
  }

  //populate object variable
  Dts.Variables["User::YourObjectVariable"].Value = fileList;
  ```